# Finding nearest "ancestor" in tree of types

Tags: c++, templates

I am forming a "tree" of types in the following way:

```
template <typename T, typename PARENT, typename ... CHILDREN>
class Node {};

class X;
class A;
class AA;
class AB;
class B;
class BA;
class BB;

class X : public Node<X, void, A, B> {};

class A : public Node<A, X, AA, AB> {};
class AA : public Node<AA, A> {};
class AB : public Node<AB, A> {};

class B : public Node<B, X, BA, BB> {};
class BA : public Node<BA, B> {};
class BB : public Node<BB, B> {};
```

I need to write a "traits" type such that I can get the "nearest ancestor" given `CHILDREN...` and `PARENT` from within the Node base class.  For example

`nearest_ancestor<X, BB>::type` should be `B` (because B is the next accessible leaf from X "on the way to" BB)

Please let me know if what I am asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can you [edit] this and update the shown code so that it is ...valid C++ code? Specifically: classes are fully defined before they are inherited from, instead of the other way around? And the classes are, actually, defined even if they're empty, so that my C++ compiler will happily compile whatever I cut/paste out of this question and into an empty file. A C++ developer will be completely confused. It looks like C++. But it is not C++.

Comment: `B` is a _child_ of `X`. How can it be the common ancestor of `X` and anything else? Is `nearest_ancestor<PARENT, LEAF>` supposed to give the child of `PARENT` which leads to `LEAF`?

Comment: @Useless Perhaps my terminology is wrong.  What I'm trying to answer is: "to traverse from X to BB, what types do I need to go through?"

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/24518718/2567683 (answers and comments therein extend far beyond the premise of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Assuming the `Node` base class has the following:

```
template <typename T, typename PARENT, typename ... CHILDREN>
class Node {
    using parent_type = PARENT;
};
```

Then `nearest_ancestor` can be defined as:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename ENABLE = void>
struct nearest_ancestor {
    using type = typename nearest_ancestor<T, typename U::parent_type>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct nearest_ancestor<T, U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, typename U::parent_type>>> {
    using type = U;
};
```